# Best practice to map points with level

Tags: php, laravel

I have a "points" field in the users table which increments points for the user after certain actions. I want to associate this with a "level" field (e.g. Level 1 , 2 ,3 ... etc).
I thought of creating a new table with numbers from 1 to 5000 for example, and map each range of numbers to their corresponding level. But I might need more points in the furure (maybe 100,000 points) which will make the table big. I feel there is a better solution.

Comment: One way would be to just have the minimum points value in your `levels` table. Then you could query the first value that is `>=` to the value (order by value asc). Otherwise, depending on your use case, you could just add constants to your `Points` model that specific what the different level values are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with a simple little helper function/method:

```
<?php

function getLevel($numberOfPoints) {
    if ( $numberOfPoints >= 10001 ) {
        return 'Level 3';
    } elseif ( $numberOfPoints >= 5001 ) {
        return 'Level 2';
    } elseif ( $numberOfPoints >= 1 ) {
        return 'Level 1';
    }
}

echo getLevel(52); // Level 1
echo getLevel(5000); // Level 1
echo getLevel(1233010); // Level 3
```

Extend the function with new levels as required